# To evaluate the value of derivative of composite function at point

Tags: derivatives

Given $f(x)=x^{3}+x$ and $g(x)=x^{3}-x$ for all $x\in R$.If $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function of $f$,then the derivative of the composite function $gof^{-1}$ at the point $2$ is?I am confused to find what $f^{-1}$ is?

Comment: @ Omkar Girkar: It is not so easy to find $f^{-1}$ this is a problem without finding formula for inverses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $f(x)=x^{3}+x$ and $g(x)=x^{3}-x$ for all $x\in R$. $$(gof^{-1}(x))'=g'(f^{-1}(x)).(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{g'(f^{-1}(x))}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$

$f(1)=2\Longrightarrow f^{-1}(2)=1$ and $f'(x)=3x^2+1$ and $g'(x)=3x^2-1$. Thus $$(gof^{-1}(2))'=g'(f^{-1}(2)).(f^{-1})'(2)=\frac{g'(f^{-1}(2))}{f'(f^{-1}(2))}=\frac{g'(1)}{f'(1)}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to write a general formula for $f^{-1}(x)$, but you can still answer the question.

It should be clear that $f(1)=2$, and $f'(1)=4$. Therefore, we have $f^{-1}(2)=1$, and by the Inverse Function Theorem, $(f^{-1})'(2)=\frac14$. Can you put the pieces together from there?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^3+x$ is bijective function and $f(1)=2$ it's mean that $f^{-1}(2)=1$ and $g(f^{-1}(2))=g(1)=0$